# How do you publish ports from a Docker container on a system using nftables?

Tags: docker, nftables

I have a fairly plain Debian Buster install. Debian Buster uses nftables rather than iptables. If I try and run a container with a published port:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name=port-test -p 1234:1234/tcp debian:jessie-slim
```

then I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint port-test (941052b9f420df39ac3d191dcbe12e97276703903911e7b5172663e7736d59e0):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:1234 ! -i docker0: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Chain 'DOCKER' does not exist
```

How do I get port publishing working?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue and comment:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26824#issuecomment-517046804

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables` and `sudo update-alternatives --config ip6tables` (if you use IPv6), and set it to `iptables-legacy` which is a compatibility mode that Docker can work with.